# Grammar: Past perfect tense

Tags: past-tense, perfect-aspect

If someone just told me about some celebrity I didn't know about all my life. would it be natural to express this in past perfect tense.
For instance: 
Someone tells me about me about Mohammed Ali and that's my first time of ever hearing about him.
 When he's finished, would it be right to say 'I hadn't heard about him all my life.' 
in a nutshell, could past perfect tense also express the past of the just past event/just finished event?

could anyone explain this to me elaborately?

Comment: The choice of tense is correct, but it would be more idiomatic to say  "I had never heard of him before" or "...in my life".

Answer (score 1):

Compare:

- If the period of not knowing continued up to the present moment now you say **I haven't heard of him** or **I have never heard of him**
- If the period ended in the past you say **I hadn't heard of him until you told me.** or **I had never heard of him until you told me.**
- You can explicitly make what your friend told you a few seconds ago in the past **I had never heard of him before you told me just now**